# Parameter change with percentage

Tags: java, if-statement, math, bluej

I have this assignment to make a class that creates product in a store.

One of the requirements is a method that changes the price according to a discount or increase percentage.

This is the method:

```
public void changePrice(double percent) {

    if ( percent > 0) {
        _price+= ((_price * percent) /100);
    }
    else if (percent < 0) {
        _price-= ((_price * percent) /100);

    }
    else {
    }
}
```

for some reason it does not recognize negative numbers, and treats them like positive.
I tried a couple of variations of this with same results.

Comment: You don't need your `if`- `else` ,  `_price+= ((_price * percent) /100);` should work for both cases .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if, else if is negating the minus in percent

```
public void changePrice(double percent) {
    _price+= ((_price * percent) /100);
}
```

If percent is +10% the price would increase by 10%
similarly if percent is -10% the price will reduce by 10%